# Keeping power shell console open after running script

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I created a script to manage my exchange server remotely the only way I can run it with powershell console staying open after execution is by running the script by browsing to the directory once in the shell console when I just double click the script it runs then closes which defeats the purpose of it.  I have tried the no exit parameter but when I use it keeps running executing the script I simply need the console to execute the script once then stay open below is my script and what I have tried is there a way to accomplish this with out editing the registry of my work desktop?

Script:

```
$UserCredential = Get-Credential  
$session = new-pssession -configurationname microsoft.exchange -connectionuri http://my exchange server/powershell/ -authentication kerberos -credential $usercredential
import-pssession $session
```

And the script that keeps executing the script over and over:

```
PowerShell -NoExit -File "C:\SomeFolder\SomePowerShellScript.ps1"
```

I have tried

```
PowerShell -NoExit -Command "Write-Host 'This window will stay open.'"
```

This allows the console to stay open but end the connection to my exchange server when I hit enter

Comment: `PowerShell -NoExit -File "C:\SomeFolder\SomePowerShellScript.ps1"` looks like the right thing to do. What, specifically, do you mean by "it keeps running executing the script"? Please clarify by updating the question directly.

Comment: Would adding `pause` at the end of `SomePowerShellScript.ps1` help?

Comment: What are your versions of powershell and exchange..?

Comment: My powershell version is 5.1 exchange is exchange server 2013

Comment: adding pause at the end did not work

Comment: what I mean by keeps running the script is the it will ask for me credentials import the commands from the exchange server then repeat after completed over and over